# Confusion over Win32 CreateProcess

Tags: c++, winapi

I am confused by the first 2 params, module and command-line. I find unless I populate both it doesn't work right, and it seems the documentation says otherwise.

I want to call "testApp.exe param1=123"

The only way I found that works is:

```
CreateProcess("testApp.exe","testApp.exe param1=123",...
```

I thought either of these should work, but no luck so far:

```
CreateProcess("testApp.exe","param1=123",...
CreateProcess(NULL,"testApp.exe param1=123",...
```

I've read the msdn docs a few times so what am I missing?

Comment: Is that your *exact* code with the exact command line? (BTW, note that the command line cannot be a string literal; the argument must be a non-`const` string.)

Comment: `The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.`

Comment: Is your point that you think you're safe because you're not using the Unicode version?  That still doesn't make it a good idea. (That was meant as general advice, not as an answer to your question.)

Comment: The point was I don't think your first comment is correct "cannot be a string literal", unless you qualify it.

Comment: Okay, fine.  I should have said that it "shouldn't be a string literal".  However, Microsoft says that the Unicode version mutates the string, but it doesn't make any promise that the ANSI version won't.  It's a very bad idea anyway in case you ever compile with UNICODE in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter is the name of the executable to run. The second parameter is the command line. The command-line need not contain the name of the executable, if it doesn't however and you pass something like

```
"param1 param2"
```

then in your program, `argv[0] == "param1"` and `argv[1] == "param2"`. Therefore, you usually have to pass the name of the executable as the first value to satisfy the program's requirements, not Windows'.

If you do not pass the executable name, it is extracted from the first value in the command line string.

Comment: The process being called is a C# app, with `static int Main(string[] args)` where the executable name is _not_ included. Is that the issue?

Comment: @John, the command-line is always passed to the process as a single string (exactly the string that you pass as a second parameter to `CreateProcess`), it is up to the process' runtime to parse it. Whether C# ignores the first token in that string is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I discuss issues with getting CreateProcess to run exes in an article [here](http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/w32tip46.htm). There are multiple things that can go wrong, including the requirement for fully qualified paths, and absent exe names in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving name of executable try to give full path with name of executable.